# Is it possible to know the name of ocean with inverse geocoder in android?

Tags: android, google-geocoder

I try to get name city and Country of something coordinates but when I have coordinates in the ocean do not get the name. What could I do?

Comment: Is it going into international waters? These belong to nobody.

Comment: Some coordinates are near the coast and should be in international waters, it could display the name of the ocean. eg pacific ocean.

Comment: International Waters = belong to nobody :)

Answer (score 0):

[Geonames](http://www.geonames.org/export/web-services.html) Reverse Geocoding Webservices can do it:
http://api.geonames.org/extendedFindNearby?lat=40.78343&lng=-43.96625&username=demo